# Как сделать приложение vk api "Desktop'ным"

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Решил попробовать себя в vk api, решил использовать пайтон, написал простенький код:

```
import vk

session = vk.AuthSession(app_id= 'мой_айди', access_token='мой_токен')
vk_api = vk.API(session)
vk_api.wall.post(message="Hello World!!! I am the first message by python app with vk api :)", v='5.74')
```

Но возвращаемая ошибка указывала на то, что у меня нет прав

```
vk.exceptions.VkAPIError: 15. Access denied: no access to call this method.
```

Решил создать новый токен, начинаю создавать, добавил право работы с сообщениями, и он сказал мол мое приложение не "десктопное" и ты не имеешь прав на это.

```
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"Only desktop applications have access to user messages"}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Добавьте в `vk.AuthSession` следующее: `scope='wall'`

Comment: @Alban Добавил, результата не дало, та же ошибка

Answer (score 0):

После часа мучений и поисков нашел решение.

Так как у меня проблема с доступом с ключом, то я решил найти проблему именно в нем, и в поддержке вк нашел подробное описание возвращаемого значения 15 и наконец-то нашел что-то дельное. В частности

> ***Также обратите внимание, что права wall игнорируются при серверной авторизации.***

И я начал гуглить по этой теме, и нашел [замечательную статью](https://flapps.ru/forum/topic5340.html), выделю определенные моменты:

1. [OpenApi](https://vk.com/dev/openapi) - попробуем вызвать метод wall.post.

> Внимание, данное право доступа недоступно для сайтов (игнорируется при попытке авторизации)

В итоге появился запрос на создание записи на стене

2. [OAuth 2.0](https://vk.com/dev/access_token?20%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) (я его и использовал)

Авторизация проходит без проблем, многие методы API работают.

Но при вызове метода wall.post сервер API возвращает ошибку:

> Permission to perform this action is denied for non-standalone
>   applications

**Вывод**: OAuth 2.0 не подходит для отправки сообщений на стену пользователя

Попробую использовать OpenAPI, о результате отпишу

Comment: Нужно просто взять да сделать Standalone/Desktop приложение https://vk.com/editapp?act=create - OAuth тут совершенно ни при чём и через него wall.post тоже работает (но только для Desktop-приложений, естественно)

Comment: @andreymal Я был абсолютно убежден, что я создал standalone приложение, я благодарен за помощь в нахождении ошибки.